# Tweepy Python Tuple Error no attribute encode

Tags: python, twitter, tuples, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am using tweepy and python to gather tweets based on certain keywords and then writing those status updates (tweets) to a CSV file. I do not consider myself a programmer and I am really lost on this.

Here is the Error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./combined-tweepy.py", line 58, in <module>
    sapi.filter(track=[topics])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 286, in filter
    encoded_track = [s.encode(encoding) for s in track]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
import tweepy
import codecs
import datetime

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Create a list of topics
with open('termList.txt', 'r') as f:
  topics = [line.strip() for line in f]

stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
topicFile = open(stamp + '.csv', 'w+')
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(topicFile))
sapi.filter(track=[topics])

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, output_file, api=None):
        super(CustomStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.output_file = output_file

    def on_status(self, status):
        ### Writes one tweet per line in the CSV file
        cleaned = status.text.replace('\'','').replace('&amp;','').replace('&gt;','').replace(',','').replace("\n",'')
        self.num_tweets = self.num_tweets + 1
        if self.num_tweets < 500:
            self.output_file.write(status.user.location.encode("UTF-8") + ',' + cleaned.encode("UTF-8") + "\n")
            print ("capturing tweet from list")
            # print status.user.location
            return True
        else:
            return False
            sys.exit("terminating")

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True #Don't kill the stream

f.close()
```

Comment: does 'termList.txt' has something called encode in it?

Comment: I am not sure how to put this in a list format in a comment: BlackStone
ViceLords
Piru
Crips
Barrio Azteca
FBD
624
BDS
MLD
Nortenos
Tangos
Vallucos
Orejas
Foritos
Houstone
Surenos
Trinitarios
Armanian
Assyrian
Nuestra
Syndicate
Hammerskins
Lowriders
Volksfront
Capirucha
Corpitos
Tangos
Mandingo
Pocos
Tongs
Salvatrucha
MS-13
Sureno
915
 one of the topics is 915 and 624, area codes representing a gang.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [definition of a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) according to Python's documentation. It seems like one of the words in *topics* is a tuple.

I see other little errors. First, the way you wrote your code, you should  call your functions after you have defined them. For example, these two lines

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(topicFile))
sapi.filter(track=[topics])
```

should come after you have defined all the functions in

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
```

Also, there's no need to put *topics* in braces

```
sapi.filter(track=[topics])
```

since it's already a list according to this line

```
topics = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Can you show us the content of termList.txt?

Comment: I put this in the comment above, one entry per line in the txt file.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the way your list of topics is constructed. Try correcting the little errors that I've found in your code before. Maybe, it'll help. For the moment, I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: Thanks blue_chip I will see where this leads me.